# Fill image in skewed container mask - Responsive - CSS3

Tags: css, responsive-design, skew

I'm working on creating skewed mask containers for images.

Problem I'm having is making the image fill the container in a responsive layout using bootstrap.

I tried to use css property background image and set `background-size: cover;` but the background image gets skewed with the container.

I will try to set an image inside the container and center / match height and width of the container.

Please take a look at my fiddle here.
http://jsfiddle.net/RyU9W/3/

**EDIT**

I Found a [plugin](http://christianvarga.com/2011/05/jquery-resize-image-to-parent-container-plugin/) that does what I need almost, although I need to adjust for the extra height and width of the container cause by the skewing.

Updated Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/RyU9W/5/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="profile">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="detail"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="profile">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/700/1350" alt=""></div>           
        <div class="detail"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.profile .image {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 400px;
    background: #000 url(http://placekitten.com/g/700/1350) center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    transform:skew(0deg,-30deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(0deg,-20deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:skew(0deg,-30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */            
}
.profile .image img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -150px;
}
.profile .image * {
    position: relative;
    transform:skew(0deg,30deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(0deg,30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:skew(0deg,30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You still should be able to use

```
background-size: cover;
```

and since your background image gets skewed with the container, set a css rule for it
with negative skew values which will revert image to its original form.

In your case it would be `transform:skew(0deg,30deg);`

Comment: This is old, but the solution in my second fiddle works well for me.

The reason background cover wont work is because it would need to be applied to the skewed container. If it's applied to an element inside the transformed container the height won't match the transformed container, as the browser doesn't recognize the height after the transform. I needed to match the height of the parent container using a trig calculation in javascript and adding that to the  image with a -margin to push it up.